# Can a handler object in Android be forced to finish execution of runnables in its queue?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

I'm using a handler object to perform delayed actions, giving the user an option to cancel the task. But if the user closes the app before the delay, the runnables are not executed.

Is there a reliable way to ensure that the handler calls the runnables before the app finishes?

```
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // blah blah
            // code code
        }
    };
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, Constants.delay);
```

Also note that I'm doing all this on the main thread.

Comment: Store all the enqueued `Runnable` objects in a set or list, and manually execute them all when your app is moved to the background?

Comment: That is what I am doing at the moment. I was hoping there was a cleaner solution. :)

Comment: There is no public API to do this. Of course, you can create your own subclass of `Handler` with methods to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have decided to circumvent the problem by storing the 'data' the runnables were using and calling a function on it.